# Conversion of msec to jiffies

Tags: c, linux, device-driver

i am using msecs_to_jiffies(msecs) to get delay. I need a delay of 16 ms. But the problem is the function return 1 for input 1-10, 2 for 11-20, 3 for 21-30 and son on. Hence i am unable to set proper delay. I can set delay only in factors of 10 ms. I can't change the HZ value and the function cant sleep also.

Kindly suggest solution to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that doing a delay of 16ms _without sleeping_ is quite bad, as whichever method you might figure out would tie down the CPU for 16ms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your system HZ value is set to 100.

If you wish to suspend execution for a period of time in a resolution lower then the system HZ, you need to use high resolution timers (which use nsec resolution, not jiffies) supported in your board and enabled in the kernel. See here for the interface of how to use them: http://lwn.net/Articles/167897/

So, either change the system HZ to 1000 and get a jiffie resolution of 1 msec or use a high resolution timer.

Comment: Even with a higher-resolution timer or a jiffie resolution of 1 msec, there is no guarantee that the thread will sleep/delay for only 16msec (even with some wiggle room). You'd need specialized hardware and interrupts.

Comment: As it's a kernel driver, there might not be a scheduled entity such as a thread. A device driver can easily tie down the kernel without being pre-empted if it wishes, it's a bad idea though.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi you don't need specialized hardware apart from a timer capable of supporting one-off mode and the needed resolution. You do need an OS capable of real time operations, which Linux is, with the Linux-RT patch. See: https://www.osadl.org/Single-View.111+M59e3481cdfe.0.html for some latency numbers

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the RT patch - it's a rather impressive and ambitious project with lots of real-world applications. Without it though, only specialized hardware can help.

Answer (score 4):

You *can't* sleep for exactly 16ms. You can sleep for *at least* 16ms, but not 16ms. That's not the way Linux (or any other desktop OS) works - they're not realtime OSes and they are scheduled in a non-deterministic manner and there's nothing you can do about it.

Whatever you're trying to do, you'll have to go about it another way. With what little info you've provided, all I can say is that what you're trying to do can't be done.